# Decomposition of scoring rule for array (not just list-like) inputs should be supported yet gives an error

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I have gotten the `model_diagnostics.scoring` function `decompose` to work for list-like inputs, such as the example in the documentation.

```py
from model_diagnostics.scoring import SquaredError, decompose
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
se = SquaredError()
y_true = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
y_pred = [0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.99, 0.9]
decompose(y_true, y_pred, scoring_function = se)
```

In a particular context, we can take this decomposition as giving various measures related to the Brier score that are of interest in statistics. However, Brier score makes sense for matrices (multi-class or multi-label problems) that compare arrays (matrices) of categories and arrays of probabilities of the categories, and I would be interested in the decomposition in such a setting, too. However, the `decompose` function is not working in the way that it seems it should.

```py
from model_diagnostics.scoring import SquaredError, decompose
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2023)
se = SquaredError()
y_true = np.random.multinomial(1, np.ones(3)/3, 10)
y_pred = np.random.dirichlet(np.ones(3), 10)
decompose(y_true, y_pred, scoring_function = se)
decompose(y_true.T, y_pred.T, scoring_function = se)
decompose(y_true.T, y_pred, scoring_function = se)
decompose(y_true, y_pred.T, scoring_function = se)
```

The first two attempts at using `decompose` fail with the `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` error message. (The last two also failed, though they were just my semi-desperate attempts to get it to work that I knew would fail.)

However, the documentation for `decompose` mentions that the inputs can be array-like, so I seem to want to do something the documentation says is supported. What gives? How can I work with arrays?